# How to download YouTube videos via HTTPS

Tags: download, ubuntu-12.04, wget, youtube, https

I am unable to access YouTube on http. But I can access the same on an https.

When I executed the command `wget https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw` it returned the following response:-

```
--2013-03-04 13:09:28--  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw
Resolving www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)... 74.125.236.167, 74.125.236.160, 74.125.236.164, ...
Connecting to www.youtube.com (www.youtube.com)|74.125.236.167|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Please guide me on how to download the YouTube videos on HTTPS

Comment: You do know that just `wget`ing the page won't get you the actual YouTube video?

Comment: what do i do then?

Comment: You could try something like [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/)

Comment: youtube-dl is giving the following error:- `[youtube] Setting language [youtube] StJLvbPIvTw: Downloading video webpage [youtube] StJLvbPIvTw: Downloading video info webpage ERROR: "token" parameter not in video info for unknown reason`

Comment: Asking for advice on how to illegally make copies of copyrighted work is off-topic for [su].

Comment: Where does it say that it is copyrighted? It's just that the youtube is banned here.

Comment: Is it banned in your geographic location, or on the network you're currently on? Most banning methods would interrupt ANY network communication between your network and the banned site/service, not just HTTP traffic.

Comment: It was banned in the company where I was working, in the network. No longer working with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found from some other Question:- Use the URL savefrom.net and type in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw . Press Download button and you can download it in any format :)) No matter whether you access it via HTTPS or HTTP

you can download the chrome app also from here>> http://en.savefrom.net/user.php
[image]